# Getting "undefined" value Ajax json while i try to get values from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to fetch values from mysql database through AJAX Request in json format. So basically AJAX gets php script. For some reason it does not get proper values, instead it shows "undefined".[pic from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIMh5.png)

[pic of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WtTF.png)

## ot5a.html

[pic from html document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of81E.png)

## ot5a.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "ot5a.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result) {
        tulostaluettelo(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});

function tulostaluettelo(result) {
    var luettelo = "<table><thead><tr><th>id</th><th>Joukkue</th><th>Voitot</th><th>Tasapelit</th><th>Tappiot</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        luettelo += "<tr><td>" + result[i].id + "</td><td>" + result[i].joukkue + "</td><td>" + result[i].voitot + "</td><td>" + result[i].tasapelit + "</td><td>" + result[i].tappiot + "</td></tr>";
    }
    luettelo += "</tbody></table>";
    $("#tulostusalue").html(luettelo);
} });
```

## ot5a.php

[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN8Lb.png)

## config.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1lv5.png)

Comment: What is the output if you do `console.log(result)` within `tulostaluettelo()`?

Comment: it does print anything. just xhr has finished loading get and file name ot5a.php and json object with proper vallues

Comment: Check network for what php is returning in response. From there you will get if the issue is with php or client side. If response is right, then there is issue with client side binding.

Comment: Do you mean checking network from configuration  files? if so where i can find them? Or Should i check web server log files?

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoint/debugger in client,php and config file and check what is the result it is returning. That way you will come to know where exactly is the problem.
Also I see that "luettelo" is a variable type, but you are iterating  it like an array object. Change that as well and see if that works.

Comment: I tried to debug my js file, and it says $ is undefined? why? I have linked jquery to my html file

Comment: Is jquery loading properly before your ot5a.js file is loaded? My guess is Jquery from CDN is taking loger time to load before your js file.

Comment: According to mine Chromes web console's network panel it take zero millisecond to load jquery.min file (it comes from cache, can i change it some how?) and two milliseconds to load my html document.

Comment: I changed to not minified version and it caches everything. why?